# what is the role of ibiblio in Maven?

Tags: maven

I am going through a Maven tutorial and it mentions that you can lookup information about a dependency on ibiblio.org:

> Let's add another dependency to our project. Let's say we've added
>   some logging to the code and need to add log4j as a dependency. First,
>   we need to know what the groupId, artifactId, and version are for
>   log4j. We can browse ibiblio and look for it, or use Google to help by
>   searching for "site:www.ibiblio.org maven2 log4j". The search shows a
>   directory called /maven2/log4j/log4j (or
>   /pub/packages/maven2/log4j/log4j). In that directory is a file called
>   maven-metadata.xml. Here's what the maven-metadata.xml for log4j looks
>   like...

Does ibiblio have some sort of special role in Maven? Or is it just a mirror?

Comment: In my memory ibiblio was a repository outside maven central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ibiblio has no special role in maven. It's just a suggestion on how to search for Maven artifacts. Nowadays, most projects just have a page documenting how they should be used in a maven project - e.g., see [log4j's documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html#Using_Log4j_in_your_Apache_Maven_build).

Answer (score 1):

Ibiblio is a repository outside maven central.

See [link to ibiblio](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/)

I would use mvnrepository to search dependencies

See [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

To learn a bit more about maven repositories you should look this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)